# How to access global variables into java and native code while working on JNI

Tags: android-studio, java-native-interface

I am working on JNI as i converted all c code in JNI format now i want access for global variables ,macros,struct in both java and native file as i have all those variables in natives header file so i can access it from native,

i tried with getter and setter it is working but due to too many variables it will take too much time to write getter and setter for all variables, so can someone suggest any method other than getter and setter to call global variables in both java and native file.

Comment: You can generate a getter and setter in Android Studio. Just right-click inside the editor and click on "Generate" -> "Getter & Setter"

Comment: yes its working but it comes for only struct and setter & getter generates in header file where the declaration are present, should i put generated setter & getter in other cpp file

Comment: Just let SWIG generate the getters and setters for you...

Comment: yes i tried SWIG but because of less knowledge its look very confusing for me if you have anything about it please let me know

Comment: You feed it a header file containing all the declarations of your global variables and it spits out java code to interact with those variables. Exactly what you wanted. You can mitigate the "less knowledge" aspect by _reading the documentation_ just as everyone before you did.